# Website is hit when cache expires and it's run on IIS via Visual Studio, but not when it's run on IIS directly

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, scheduled-tasks, global-asax

I am using a dummy page and cache timeout in Global.asax to run a scheduled task, exactly like it is described here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc

When I run this via Visual Studio using the local IIS web server (*not* IIS Express), the dummy page is hit every two minutes. But when I run it through IIS directly, my dummy page is never hit.

Any idea why that might be? It is the exact same code and the sites are set up the same way on IIS 7.5.

**Edit:**
My dummy page url is in the format `http://10.1.0.3:8080/Dummy` as opposed to `http://localhost/Dummy.aspx` like in the linked example because I am using MVC/Razor... If that helps.

Comment: I don't know if this applies to your situation, but one problem I have encountered in the past has been page caching.  Try adding a dummy timestamp variable to your dummy page URL, and see if it helps.  Something like `"http://my.url.com?TS=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString ()`.

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious but... Same app pool, same version of the Framework, etc.?

Comment: @Basic Yes it is the same.

Comment: Next question.... You say it works only when run from VS - I assume you're deploying to local IIS and letting VS attach a debugger? Can you check if it's the fact that it was deployed from VS or that there is a debugger attached by removing/reattaching VS to `w3svc`? Also, does restarting IIS make a difference? There shouldn't be any functional difference assuming app pools are the same (which you've checked). One last thought... Try writing to file in the timeout callback handler - that way at least you'll know where your loop is broken. I assume you can browse to your dummy page w/o VS?